# python: make 3 dimensional list element values all to zero

Tags: python, list

I want to make all elements of a 3 dimensional array to zero without calling three for loops.

```
list= [[[1,2],[3,4,11]],[[5,6,12,13],[7,8,14]]]
```

into

```
list= [[[0,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0]]]
```

I don't want to call 3 for loops to do individual assignment.
Is there a single function to do this operation.

Comment: It seems like you have actually answered your own question.

Answer (score 1):

In pure python you have to loop. But if you can use another numerical libraries you can use `numpy`:

```
In [13]: arr = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]])

In [15]: arr = np.zeros(arr.shape)

In [16]: arr
Out[16]: 
array([[[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]]])
```

As @ Blckknght mentioned in comment, if you want to change the items in-place you better to use a simple slice assignment, instead of creating new array using `np.zeros()`:

```
In [4]: arr[:] = 0

In [5]: arr
Out[5]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 0]],

       [[0, 0],
        [0, 0]]])
```

Comment: This question is *specifically about lists*.

Comment: Note that if you can use numpy and you want the array to be modified in place (rather than creating a new array and replacing the original with it), you simply need a slice assignment: `arr[:] = 0`. You can also index with `...` (the literal for the obscure Python singleton `Ellipsis`) if you prefer to be explicit that you want to broadcast over all dimensions rather than just the first (`arr[...] = 0`).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I'd say that "use numpy" is often the most correct answer when someone asks about how to do some operation all at once to a nested numeric data structure. It may or may not be applicable here, depending on whether the questioner's real data has unmatched lengths of the lists in some dimensions or not.

Comment: @Blckknght Indeed that's the best way for in-place modification. I just used the `np.zeros` because of the OP's request for using a function. And made me forgot about other ways. Thanks for mentioning that!

Comment: @Kasramvd as Blckknght mentioned, the solution is applicable only when lengths of lists match at all levels. In the example given by OP lenght of the deepest lists mismatchs

Comment: @abukaj This is an answer based on the question before edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehensions:

```
[[[0 for k in m] for m in l] for l in lst]
```

Comment: I've renamed `list` to `lst` as one of Python native types is already called this name.

Comment: list comprehension is a syntactic sugar for loop